# Arithmetic Progression-Question from Hall and Knight's Higher Algebra

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question says-

> Between two numbers whose sum is $\frac{13}{6}$, an even number of arithmetic means is inserted such that the sum of these means exceeds their number by unity. How many means are there?

Comment: What does an 'arithmetic mean' mean, in this case?  Is it meant to suggest that the intermediate numbers are evenly spaced between the two endpoints?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki " Between two quantities it is always possible to insert any number of terms such that the whole series thus formed shall be in Arithmetic Progression; and the terms inserted are thus known as **Arithmetic Means**.

Comment: With that definition, you're unlikely to get far, as then your condition will look like $\frac{13}4 \times 2m - 2m = 1 \implies m = \frac29$.

Comment: In theory the 'Gauss trick' should be applicable to this problem, but the resulting equation yields a non-integer solution for the number of means.  I suspect there's something one or the other of us is missing, but I don't immediately see what offhand.

Comment: @AlokRanjan, pls tell me the page number.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The answer given at the back is $12$.

Comment: @Vikram Pg.34.....Question 7

Comment: Alok: then that means there's a typo in the book; the correct value to give the result you quote should be $\frac{13}{6}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'm damn sure that didn't miss anything in the question.... By the way the no. is a mixed fraction- $2\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: @AlokRanjan, you typed the prob incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is given that $a+l=\frac{13}{6}$

Let $2n$ be the number of arithmetic means inserted

$\therefore$ total number of terms = $2+2n$

$l=a+(2+2n-1)d=a+(2n+1)d$, add $a$ to both the sides to get $a+l=2a+(2n+1)d$

$\therefore 2a+(2n+1)d=\frac{13}{6}$. . . . . . (I)

Let the sum of the arithmetic means $=a_1+a_2+...+a_{2n}$

$\therefore (a_1+a_2+...+a_{2n}) -1=2n$

$\therefore$ sum of the entire A series=$2n+1+\frac{13}{6}$

$\therefore 2n+1+\frac{13}{6}=\frac{2n+2}{2}(2a+(2n+2-1)d)$

$2n+\frac{19}{6}=(n+1)(2a+(2n+1)d)$

Substitute from (I) and solve for $n$ and then find $2n$

Answer (score 2):

(This is a solution for the fixed problem with the sum of the two numbers being $\frac{13}{6}$)

Hint: use the 'Gauss trick' for arithmetic sums...

> Assume that there are $n$ means, with $n$ even; then each mean can be paired off with a counterpart such that the two sum to $\frac{13}{6}$.  This means that the total sum of all the means is $\frac{13}{6}\cdot\frac{n}{2} = \frac{13}{12}n$, and of course one more than their number is $n+1$.  Now, just solve the resulting linear equation to find $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the total progression be:

$a, a+d, a+2d,...,a+(n+1)d$

We have

$2a+(n+1)d=13/6$

and

$\frac{n(2a+(n+1)d)}{2}=\frac{n\cdot 13/6}{2}=n+1$

Solve for n.

Answer (score 1):

This is problem number 7 from page 34, Examples IV. b.

The complete solution of this problem from page 9 of [http://www.amazon.com/Solutions-Examples-Higher-Algebra-LaTeX/dp/150876350X/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/150876350X) is

[image: Solution to problem 7, Examples IV. b.]

Comment: Indian edition : http://www.flipkart.com/solutions-examples-higher-algebra-latex-edition-english/p/itme6krr9pfvv3ap?pid=9781508763505

Comment: http://www.amazon.in/dp/150876350X